# Best practice to initialize variable in classes, accessible for all methods in C#

Tags: c#

Can i have variables which are accessible and initialized, accessible for all class methods?
I have a class which has only methods and I do not create an object from, yet I want all methods to have a few mutual variables e.g., in this case

Dictionary callBacks

```
class Person
{

        public static void do(Button va, Dictionary<string, CallBack> callBacks)
        {
            callBacks["do1"].Press(va);
            callBacks["do2"].Press(va);
        }

        public static void go(dynamic va, Dictionary<string, CallBack> callBacks)
        {
            callBacks["go1"].Press(va);
            callBacks["go2"].Press(va);
        }

        public static void sit(dynamic va, Dictionary<string, CallBack> callBacks)
        {
            callBacks["sit1"].Press(va);
            callBacks["sit2"].Press(va);
        }

        public static void eat(dynamic va, Dictionary<string, CallBack> callBacks)
        {
            callBacks["eat1"].Press(va);
            callBacks["eat2"].Press(va);
        }
}
```

I pass callBacks from the calling class but i'd rather define it in the person class or access it from the parent.

In the parent I define it as:

```
callBacks = someVariable.other;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dictionary of callbacks is the same and does not change you can declare it as a [static readonly property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members) of your `Person` class:

```
class Person
{
        public static readonly Dictionary<string, CallBack> Callbacks  = 
                new Dictionary<string, CallBack> 
                {
                   {"do1", new CallBack(....)},
                   {"do2", new CallBack(....)},
                   .....
                };

        public static void do(Button va)
        {
            Callbacks["do1"].Press(va);
            Callbacks["do2"].Press(va);
        }
        .......
}
```

Other classes will be able to access it via `Person.Callbacks` syntax.

**UPD**

If you need to pass it from above then I suggest you change your methods from being static to being instance and passing the callbacks via constructor:

```
class Person
{ 
        public Person(Dictionary<string, CallBack> callbacks)
        {
              Callbacks = callbacks;
        }             

        private readonly Dictionary<string, CallBack> Callbacks;

        public void do(Button va)
        {
            Callbacks["do1"].Press(va);
            Callbacks["do2"].Press(va);
        }
        .......
}
```

Comment: in my case the dictionary object is passed from a higher hierarchy.
I cannot define it as you showed